# Disable parts of the 2017 Macbook's trackpad?

Tags: macos, macbook, touchpad

I'm forced to use a Macbook at work and I really dislike the trackpad. It has horrible palm detection, so it often registers unintended inputs. Is there a way to disable the edges of the trackpad? E.g. I only need about half of the trackpad, so I want to disable the other half. I'm considering putting tape on the trackpad, is there a way with software?

Answer (score 3):

This question is partly answered in this post: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/322252.

There is a software you can install which allows you to reduce the tracking area: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

There is another answer on the same link which explains how you can use a tape as a hack to ignore part of the trackpad: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/262149